# TypeError: __dict__ must be set to a dictionary, not a 'unicode'

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode, ipython

I cloned a library from git and I just managed to use the `savePlayerDictionary` method.

I stored the json file and everything looks fine.

BUT

When I try to use the loadPlayerDictionary, I get the error:

```
TypeError: __dict__ must be set to a dictionary, not a 'unicode'
```

My code:

```
def savePlayerDictionary(playerDictionary, pathToFile):
    """
    Saves player dictionary to a JSON file
    """
    player_json = {name: player_data.to_json() for name, player_data in playerDictionary.items()}
    json.dump(player_json, open(pathToFile, 'wb'), indent=0)


def loadPlayerDictionary(pathToFile):
    """
    Loads previously saved player dictionary from a JSON file
    """
    result = {}
    with open(pathToFile, "r") as f:
        json_dict = json.load(f)
        for player_name in json_dict:
            parsed_player = Player(None,None,False)
            parsed_player.__dict__ = json_dict[player_name]
            result[player_name] = parsed_player
    return result
```

where `player_data.to_json()` is implemented as:

```
def to_json(self):
    return json.dumps(self.__dict__)
```

The code I run is:

```
get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
import basketballCrawler as bc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

players = bc.loadPlayerDictionary("myJson.json")
```

Comment: Why are you assigning to `__dict__` in the first place? I'd use `__dict__.update()`. But clearly `json_dict[player_name]` is not a dictionary.

Comment: What does the `to_json()` method return?

Comment: The to_json method is:
def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Provide a *small* sample JSON file so the load operation reproduces the problem.  Delete unnecessary code such as the save, since it works and is unneeded if you provide the JSON file it generates.  Provide the full traceback so we can see how it fails.

Comment: So you are encoding to JSON twice. Don't do that; return just the `__dict__`, or make sure to decode twice when loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding your player data to JSON, then encoding the whole dictionary mapping names to that JSON data to JSON *again*, resulting in double-encoded JSON data for the values of that mapping.

When you decode, you only decoded the name-data mapping, not the data for each player. You'd need to decode that separately:

```
parsed_player = Player(None,None,False)
parsed_player.__dict__ = json.loads(json_dict[player_name])
```

It'd be easier if you just not encoded in `to_json()`:

```
def to_json(self):
    return vars(self)
```

(I used the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) as a cleaner function to get the same dictionary).

If all you are doing is persisting your player data, then consider using the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) instead; it is faster and more versatile, no need to have a separate song and dance with `__dict__` attributes. There is a wrapper module called [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) that builds on `pickle` to create a persisted dictionary for objects even.